# Which is better practice when setting headers for a fetch in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, http-headers, fetch-api

What's the difference between setting up headers for a fetch with new Headers() object, like so.

```
const headers = new Headers()
headers.set('User','Bob')
```

Versus assigning the desired headers with less code and not using the new Header() class.

```
const headers = { User: 'Bob'}
```

When performing a `fetch` in JavaScript.
And if both harvest a similar result which one is best practice when fetching data?

Comment: You've probably noticed that your `fetch` works either way. There are differences between the litteral and the instance of Header (the instance has useful methods), but why do you care ? Why is it a *problem* ?

Comment: I was curious which way is best practice to use because people use both ways interchangeably, so I thought to ask.

 I also thought other new developers might find this useful in the future, even though some thought it was a dumb question. I also think a lot xD

Comment: I am confused why this was downvoted. When learning this stuff it is sometimes helpful to get a high-level overview to determine importance. This instance being that in JS you can create the same thing in different ways - but more importantly that Headers is just a simple object! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Headers` object behaves similar to a `Map` except the key difference is that the header keys are case insensitive.

headers:

```
var headers = new Headers();

headers.set('CONTENT-tYpE', 'text/html');

console.log(headers.get('content-type')); // text/html
```

map:

```
var headers = new Map();

headers.set('CONTENT-tYpE', 'text/html');

console.log(headers.get('content-type')); // undefined
```

object:

```
var headers = {};

headers['CONTENT-tYpE'] = 'text/html';

console.log(headers['content-type']); // undefined
```

(when passed to fetch or a http request, all header names are normalized regardless of data type)

Comment: Another minor difference is that a `Headers` has an `.append()` method, using which you can set multiple values for the same header, while you can't do that with a `Map`

Answer (score -3):

I'm so tired of people trying to define a single "best practice" for everything in JavaScript. The answer here is that there is no "better" way as far as the *fetch* API is concerned.

Depending on what you do before calling *fetch*, the litteral object or the instance of Headers may seem *nicer*. For example, getting hardcoded headers from a JSON configuration, it would be a waste of code to instantiate a Headers ; on the other hand, if you need to write some logic to generate the headers and select which ones to include, Headers has more explicit and case-insensitive (i.e. safer) methods.

But that's only my **opinion** about what I think are clear-cut examples. I'm sure there are people out there who would recommend always using litterals because they want immutability, and others who'd say Headers is more expressive and better typed. Either way, that's not what StackOverflow is for.

Comment: Who said anything about best practice or better? OP asked for the difference between two different pieces of code.

Comment: OP clarified in comments that they want "best practice". I'm not making this up.